# Can I stop Django’s site-wide caching MiddleWare from setting Cache-Control and Expires to the same values that memcached uses?

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I’m setting up a Django site to use memcached, via Django’s site-wide caching MiddleWare.

I planned to store pages in memcached for a very long time (because they don’t change very often, and because my whole site should comfortably fit into a relatively small amount of memory), and amend my code to delete pages from memcached when the data on those pages *does* change (to avoid stale pages).

However, Django’s MiddleWare sets the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP headers on its responses to the same values that memcached uses for its expiry policy. That means that if I set a very long expiry for cached pages in memcached, end users’ browsers will use that expiry too, making them more likely to get stale data.

Can I stop Django’s MiddleWare from doing this?

Comment: @saul.shanabrook: I don’t think adding a bounty to this question is the best way to get your question answered. You’d be better off asking a separate question.

Comment: My problem is exactly the same as the one you described, so I didn't want to start a duplicate question. I guess the difference is I don't want to decorate each view, I want to be able to do it sitewide.

Comment: Is there a reason not add a bounty?

Comment: @saul.shanabrook: "I guess the difference is I don't want to decorate each view, I want to be able to do it sitewide" Then your problem isn't exactly the same as the one I described. I think you're likely to get more attention on a new question than one with an accepted answer, and more likely to get good answers if you describe your problem and requirements in a question, rather than tacking the qualification on to mine below a bounty message. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add

```
@cache_control(must_revalidate=True, max_age=3600)
```

decorator to each of your views to make browsers validate their cache contents every time page is loaded. It is available by importing

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control
```

After that, if content on server is changed, then browser will redownload page from server.

Comment: Aha, okay. I guess I could just use `max_age=3600` — I’m fine with browsers caching for an hour without revalidating. I haven’t got any conditional GET MiddleWare running, so I wonder how Django would decide if the content has changed?

Comment: I think it would just run view and then compare something like hash of user content and hash of view generated content.

Comment: Ah — yeah, if it runs the view then I’m not really getting the benefit of memcached. I’ll try sticking with just `max_age` and see what happens.

Comment: If you would to put memcached decorator under `@cache_control` decorator, then `@cache_control` would have to pass trough memcached decorator, and as I know memcached tries to return cached view if there is one. After that `@cache_control` would compare with content returned by memcached, not the one view originally generates. I may be wrong tough.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created [`django-response-timeout`](https://github.com/saulshanabrook/django-response-timeout) to solve this problem on a site-wide basis. It will add the `max_age` header to all views as well as the expiry time. To install `pip install django-response-timeout`. Then add `response_timeout.middleware.SetCacheTimeoutMiddleware` to your middleware like so:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'response_timeout.middleware.SetCacheTimeoutMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

Finally set `RESPONSE_CACHE_SECONDS` to however long you want responses to be cached.

Answer (score -1):

Django docs have a whole page on [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/).  Is that not providing you with  information you need?

Specifically:

> There are a few other ways to control cache parameters. For example,
>   HTTP allows applications to do the following:
>
> Define the maximum time a page should be cached. Specify whether a
>   cache should always check for newer versions, only delivering the
>   cached content when there are no changes. (Some caches might deliver
>   cached content even if the server page changed, simply because the
>   cache copy isn't yet expired.)